# Recreate spacemacs' ivy/projectile 'SPC P SPC' binding for helm/projectile

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, helm-projectile

I recently switched from ivy to helm in spacemacs as my project search/management package.

In ivy, there is a keybinding for `SPC p SPC` that does a search for files in the project (by file name). There is a very similar method and binding for helm:  `helm-projectile-find-file`, which is bound to `SPC p f`. I want to also bind this to `SPC p SPC`, like in ivy.

My attempt at adding the keybinding, distilled from my .spacemacs is this:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "add user config here"

  ; add ivy-like shortcut
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-minor-mode 'projectile-mode (kbd "p SPC") "helm-projectile-find-file"))
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to invoke the keybinding, it does not exist.

## Additional Context / Things I have tried.

I may be binding in the wrong minor mode. I tried it on `'helm-mode` at first and that caused errors on startup. `'projectile-mode` seems kind of wrong/weird, but I couldn't find a helm + projectile mode to bind on.

The key sequence in my code may be wrong. The spacemacs docs say "use a macro like `kbd` to determine the key sequence" so that's what I'm trying to do here. `(kbd "p SPC")` evaluates to `("p ")`. I have also tried using "p SPC" directly, with no call to `kbd`, with no luck.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Thx.

Comment: Ok, I can edit the question to remove the 2 subquestions. I added them as context for what I have tried and what might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that. But the question is not clear. *"not be achieving anything"* and *"not working"* don't tell us what the problem or question is. To be a useful (acceptable) question here please clarify. Just what behavior do you want to achieve, what did you try, to achieve it, and what behavior did you get instead? A step-by-step recipe starting from `emacs -Q` is ideal, but any way you can make clear what you're asking will be better than what you have now. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for updating to clarify: the question is about a key binding that doesn't show up.

Comment: @Drew I tried again. The question has always included what I want to do and what I have tried and it still does. What I want to do is described in both the title and the body of the question.

I don't understand why I would try to replicate this with `emacs -Q`. The behaviour I am trying to achieve ties into spacemacs, projectile, and helm, as shown in the question. Without this fairly large and complete environment, the issue would not make any sense.

Comment: It's not necessarily that the key binding doesn't show up that I need help with. Any solution that allows me to have "SPC p SPC" bind to helm-projectile-find-file is sufficient. If my attempted solution is completely wrong, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided example user-config almost works! Instead of set-leader-keys-for-minor-mode, I did this:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "add user config here"

  ; add ivy-like shortcut
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "p SPC" 'helm-projectile-find-file))
```

This fixes the following issues:

1. `(kbd "p SPC")` was returning the wrong value.
2. the function was being passed in as a string, instead of a quoted symbol

Finally, this binding is now active globally, not limited to a specific minor mode, like the original configuration was. This ensures it will be active at all times.